# Personalised views for a specific Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The goal is to generate views for given class that are personalised to a given user.
Model and Controller logic remain the same, but the layout and record presentation would be subject to user preferences.

Given the unicity of User.id it is readily available to create application_controller logic to use a layout with that `id`.

```
layout = @user.layout
```

The layout would be able to invoke its personalised CSS.

But what of the views?  and the routing?  Given a class `Product`  how can the

```
resources :products
```

invoke a subdirectory of `app/views/products` to use that of the user's id, say

```
app/views/products/10
```

Thus leading to a structure of files

```
app/views/products/10/show.html.erb
app/views/products/10/edit.html.erb
app/views/products/10/index.html.erb
app/views/products/11/show.html.erb
app/views/products/11/edit.html.erb
app/views/products/11/index.html.erb
app/views/products/12/show.html.erb
app/views/products/12/edit.html.erb
app/views/products/12/index.html.erb
```

Answer (score -1):

Answering your question you have call render in each method in the controller.

```
def show
  ...
  render "user/show/#{params[:id]}.html.erb"
end
```

You have more info here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render

But, unless they are TOTALLY different it would be better using the same view for every record and keeping a field for each one with options to manipulate the view.

```
@user.layout = {header: true, footer: false, ...}
```

And in the view:

```
<% if @user.layout[:header] %> 
   <div>....</div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This is off-target and maybe the question was not sufficiently complete.  The goal is to present the views in a personalised way.  so show, edit, whatever  gets laid out according to a given set.  This is why I stated  `invoke a subdirectory `, it is assumed that subdirectory would have its own show, edit, whatever views ...

Comment: I don't see the problem, you can use this structure : ```render  "user/#{params[:id]}/show.html.erb"```

Comment: The problem lies in the fact that you are delaing with the user class, not the products class `resources :products`

Comment: You can use render method to render whatever partial you want in any folder